# Can we always choose a countable dense subset of an open set of the complex plane?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Say $G\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open. Can we always choose a countable and dense subset of $G$?.

Comment: In fact every subset of $\mathbb C$ has a finite or countable dense subset. This follows from the Lindelof property of $\mathbb C.$

Answer (score 3):

Let $K:=\{a+bi:a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. You know that $K$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$. Then $K\cap G$ is dense in $G$.

Comment: why is K dense in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @seht111 Because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.